# What does my project need to reference in order to use the Windows shell?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, thumbnails, windows-shell

Specifically, I want to use `IShellFolder`, `IExtractImage` and `ShellInterop` in order to extract thumbnails from PDF and DOC files.

Also, the namespace I need to import would be handy too

Thanks so much for taking a look at this newbie question :)

Iain

Answer (score 0):

### Namespace: SnapStream.Util

### Assembly: SnapStream (in SnapStream.dll)

```
public interface IShellFolder
public interface IExtractImage
```

I forgot to mention, that this is not a part of the framework.

Comment: Thanks very much Tommy but I can't seem to find System.Windows.Shell inside presentation framework... any other ideas?

Comment: @lain: I'm sorry I got turned around check my new answer